Ein Mishpat but for Yerushalmi
Is there a way to get the halachot that come from Yerushalmi similar to the way Ein Mishpat works on the Bavli. I can't seem to find any way to find a way to trace the gemarot to halachot.
Even places don't fully link Yerushalmi to Halacha as far as I can tell.

The Oz Vehadar edition of Talmud Yerushalmi has Ein Mishpat in the corner, just like for Talmud Bavli. You can see a (blurry) picture in the preview for their Yerushalmi editions here.
Additionally, since Artscroll uses the Oz Vehadar edition for their Yerushalmi text, you'll find the same in the Artscroll Yerushalmi.
